# array - php wrong sorting

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote an API call that should return and sort values from database in code I provided.

Anway it works, but not in a way that it should.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($myResults as $myResult => $label) {
    $result['id'][$myResult] =  $label["id"];
    $result['name'][$myResult] =  $label["name"];
    $result['totalCollected'][$myResult] =  $label["totalCollected"];
}

return $result;
```

So, this is my code and it returns..

```
"data": {
    "id": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "name": [
        "Name 1",
        "Name 2"
    ],
    "totalCollected": [
        2500,
        2000
    ]
},
```

I want to iterate an array to look like this..

```
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": Name 1,
        "value": 2500,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": Name 2,
        "value": 2000,
    }
 ]
```

Comment: `$label` __already__ has the structure that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way :

```
function sort_objects_by_total($a, $b) {
  if($a->totalCollected == $b->totalCollected){ return 0 ; }
  return ($a->totalCollected < $b->totalCollected) ? -1 : 1;
}

$result = array();
foreach ($myResults as $key => $value){
    $result[$key]['id'] =  $value["id"];
    $result[$key]['name'] =  $value["name"];
    $result[$key]['totalCollected']=  $value["totalCollected"];
}

usort($result, 'sort_objects_by_total');
$sorted_result=array_reverse($result)
return $sorted_result;
```

Comment: I would change `$result[$key]['value']=  $value["totalCollected"];` as the OP request

Answer (score 0):

You might try making sure your result items are objects.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($myResults as $myResult){
    $result[] = (object)array(
        'id' => $myResult["id"],
        'name' => $myResult["name"],
        'value'=> $myResult["totalCollected"]
    );
}
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I have done it like this. Thanks for response.

```
foreach ($schoolResults as $schoolResult => $label) {
        $result['data'][$schoolResult]["id"] = $label["id"];
        $result['data'][$schoolResult]["name"] = $label["name"];
        $result['data'][$schoolResult]["totalCollected"] = $label["totalCollected"];

    }

    return $result;
```